# Do while loop c++ assistance

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a cpp program that asks the user for two number inputs. Then print from 1 to the first number the user entered or until the first multiple of the second number. Print "Multiple of X(second number)" if the number is a multiple of the second input. using Do while loop.
This is what I managed to do so far.

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "enter two numbers: ";
    int first = 0;
    int second = 0;
    std::cin >> first >> second;

    if(second != 0 && first%second == 0)
        std::cout << first << " is a multiple of " << second << '\n' ;
    else 
    {
        int n = 0;
        int maxval = second*2 > first ? first : second*2;
        do 
            std::cout << ++n << '\n';
        while(n < maxval);
    }
}
```

I'm hoping someone can help me fix the code or point out what's wrong/missing in it.
Input should be any two numbers
then output should print numbers from 1 until the first number OR until the first multiple of the second number if it comes before the first number.
Example:
Enter two numbers: 10
7
1
2
3
4
5
6
Multiple of 7

Comment: Please [edit] and show a simple example of input and expected output.

Comment: What problem are you facing here then?

Comment: Post any updates [to you question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71349888/edit); not as a comment. Your post is missing four things: 1. example input, 2. expected output using (1), 3. actual output using (1) from your current code, and finally, 4. a *question* (you never asked a question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `break` when you get to the target number.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "enter two numbers: ";
    int first = 0;
    int second = 0;
    std::cin >> first >> second;

    if (second != 0 && first % second == 0)
        std::cout << first << " is a multiple of " << second << '\n';
    else {
        int n = 0;
        int maxval = second * 2 > first ? first : second * 2;
        do {
            if (++n % second == 0) {
                std::cout << "Multiple of " << second << '\n';
                break;
            } else {
                std::cout << n << '\n';
            }
        } while (n < maxval);
    }
}
```

https://cplayground.com/?p=marmoset-tiger-vicuna

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed my problem. Appreciated.